# select only integer from right before certain character

Tags: sql-server

I want a simple solution to select only numbers from right of a VARCHAR column
before a certain character.

For example, in the strings below, I only want to  select numbers before slash character. The numbers vary, it can be 1 digit or more.

'ST/11/SCI/**1**' 'ST/11/SCI/**22**' 'ST/11/BIO/**854**' 'ST/11/BIO/**5421**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REVERSE` with `CHARINDEX` so as to locate the position of the last `'/'` character. Then use `RIGHT` to extract the number:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'ST/11/BIO/854'
SELECT RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@str)) - 1)
```

**Edit:**

To get second number starting from the end you can use:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'ST/11/BIO/1288/544'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, q2.x + 2, q2.x - q1.x - 1) 
FROM (SELECT @str AS v) AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@str))) AS q1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@str), q1.x + 1)) AS q2(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(@str)) AS s(l)
```

Comment: Is this faster than parsename?? Which one will result in better performance?

Comment: this one is more better

Comment: @JibinBalachandran `PARSENAME` has the limitation that it works only with up to 4 parts. As far as performance is concerned you can test both solutions with your actual data. With a small set of data I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos one more question: how would it be if i want to get the number between the first slash from right and second slash?? e.g number 88 in this string: ST/11/BIO/88/544

Comment: @sqluser, did you check my XML-based answer? For the one *last* value this answer is perfect, voted on it myself... But when you want to get several parts of a string a *full-split* might be better. One great advantage was the fact, that you get your values *type-safe*...

Comment: @shungo yes, thank you - very practical and smart indeed

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, REVERSE`

**REVERSE :** It will `REVERSE` your original string value

**CHARINDEX :** It will find index/location of any character from string value

**SUBSTRING :** It will split your string value

```
DECLARE @myString as VARCHAR(50)='ST/11/SCI/22'
SELECT 
    REVERSE
    (
        SUBSTRING
        (
            REVERSE(@myString),
            0,
            CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@myString))
        )
    )
```

Comment: I do not understand the down voter. You were some minutes before Giorgos answer which is almost the same... +1 from my side...

Answer (score 2):

I poste this as another answer, because the approach is completely different to the one of my other answer:

Starting with SQL Server 2012 (thx @NEER!) there is [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx), which is a very straight approach to split a *dot-delimited string* up to 4 parts:

```
DECLARE @stringTable TABLE(string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @stringTable VALUES
 ('ST/11/SCI/1'),('ST/11/SCI/22'),('ST/11/BIO/854'),('ST/11/BIO/5421');

SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.string,'/','.'),1)
FROM @stringTable AS s
```

The result

```
1
22
854
5421
```

Comment: Is this better than `reverse` and `charindex` method?? Which has a better performance?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran, don't know... Test it and let us know :-)

Comment: This is for SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 0):

If you need all data you can split this easily and type-safe:

```
DECLARE @stringTable TABLE(string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @stringTable VALUES
 ('ST/11/SCI/1'),('ST/11/SCI/22'),('ST/11/BIO/854'),('ST/11/BIO/5421');

SELECT s.string
      ,x.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS Part1
      ,x.value('/x[2]','int') AS Part2
      ,x.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(10)') AS Part3
      ,x.value('/x[4]','int') AS Part4
FROM @stringTable AS s
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(s.string,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML)) AS A(x)
```

The result

```
string          Part1   Part2   Part3   Part4
ST/11/SCI/1     ST      11      SCI     1
ST/11/SCI/22    ST      11      SCI     22
ST/11/BIO/854   ST      11      BIO     854
ST/11/BIO/5421  ST      11      BIO     5421
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `reverse` and `charindex` :

```
select reverse(left(reverse(...), charindex('/', reverse(...)) -1))
```

Documentation of reverse : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180040.aspx

Documentation of charindex : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186323.aspx

Test: `select reverse(left(reverse('ST/11/SCI/2'), charindex('/', reverse('ST/11/SCI/2')) -1))`

Output: `2`

**Note:** We didnt know your version of SQL-Server, check the documentation of reverse/charindex to know wich version of SQL Server is supported !